# Python regex and leading 0 in capturing group

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm writing a script in python 3 to automatically rename files. But I have a problem with the captured group in a regex.

I have these kinds of files :

```
test tome 01 something.cbz
test tome 2 something.cbz
test tome 20 something.cbz
```

And I would like to have :

```
test 001 something.cbz
test 002 something.cbz
test 020 something.cbz
```

I tried several bits of code:

**Example 1**:

```
name = re.sub('tome [0]{0,1}(\d{1,})', str('\\1').zfill(3), name)
```

The result is:

```
test 01 something.cbz
test 02 something.cbz
test 020 something.cbz
```

**Example 2**:

```
name = re.sub('tome (\d{1,})', str('\\1').lstrip("0").zfill(3), name)
```

The result is:

```
test 001 something.cbz
test 02 something.cbz
test 020 something.cbz
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the `zfill(3)` on the `.group(1)` value after stripping the zeroes from the left side:

```
import re

s = ("test tome 01 something.cbz\n"
            "test tome 2 something.cbz\n"
            "test tome 20 something.cbz")

result = re.sub(
    r'tome (\d+)',
    lambda x: x.group(1).lstrip("0").zfill(3),
    s
)
print(result)
```

Output

```
test 001 something.cbz
test 002 something.cbz
test 020 something.cbz
```

Comment: I've been testing a bit and to me `lstrip("0")` made no difference. Might as well remove it?

Comment: @JvdV Try `"test tome 00000000000000000000000001 something.cbz"` without lstrip("0") https://ideone.com/SMUCla

Comment: Ah in case numbers are longer. I get it now! Didn't think of that possibility.

Answer (score 4):

Try `str.format`:

```py
import re

s = """\
test tome 01 something.cbz
test tome 2 something.cbz
test tome 20 something.cbz"""

pat = re.compile(r"tome (\d+)")

s = pat.sub(lambda g: "{:>03}".format(g.group(1)), s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
test 001 something.cbz
test 002 something.cbz
test 020 something.cbz
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zfill` like this on a lambda:

```py
import re

arr = ['test tome 01 something.cbz', 'test tome 2 something.cbz', 'test tome 20 something.cbz']

rx = re.compile(r'tome (\d+)')
for s in arr:
   print ( rx.sub(lambda m: m[1].zfill(3), s) )
```

**Output:**

```bash
test 001 something.cbz
test 002 something.cbz
test 020 something.cbz
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add another alternative:

```
import re

s_in = ("test tome 01 something.cbz\n"
     "test tome 2 something.cbz\n"
     "test tome 20 something.cbz")

s_out = re.sub(r'tome (\d+)', lambda x: ('00'+x[1])[-3:], s_in)
print(s_out)
```

Prints:

```
test 001 something.cbz
test 002 something.cbz
test 020 something.cbz
```

Comment: So you take the group 1 value, then prepend `00` and then take the list 3  characters right?

Comment: Right, hoping for no values such as `20000` in op's data @Thefourthbird.